# Proper Font Browser dialogs

Tags: winforms, user-interface, fonts, dialog

The System.Windows.Forms.FontBrowser is a pretty horrible piece of work. I'd like to write a custom one, but before I re-invent banging-two-rocks-together, I figured I'd ask if anyone knows an intuitive, friendly and above all simple Font Picker which has been proven in the cauldron of the real world?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you about how terrible is Windows default font browser.
Some time ago I started to search for a replacement fontdialog, but could not find any (even after some days searching).
So I started to develop one in VB.NET, but never got time to finish it.

This article can help you (as it helped me) to identify what a good font dialog should have. Hope this helps you somehow. [link](http://www.unifont.org/fontdialog/).

If you manage to make one, please let me know! I`d love to test and use it :)

EDIT1: This [link](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/screenshots/font) can help too.